# Trouble launching shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have recently installed shiny for R. However, when I launch shiny I get the following error:

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:42427
Error in startServer(host, port, handlerManager$createHttpuvApp()) : 
  Failed to create server

I would very much appreciate if someone could explain what this means to me...I am very new to using R and cannot seem to work it out for myself. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps have a look [here](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=17521) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613580/shiny-runexample-error-fail-to-create-server) or provide a reproducible example.