# R library gmailr's function 'gmail_auth' stopped working

Tags: r, debian, gmail-api

I have a headless Debian 9 server that's running an `R BATCH` script every night. Basically it fetches attached data from a Gmail account to produce nightly reports. This has been working flawlessly for a long time. But about a week ago, it stopped. I can't say for sure, but it might coincide with a major update to version 9 of Debian...

One of the first things the script does is to authenticate to the gmail account. Like this:

```
library(gmailr)
gmail_auth(secret_file = 'lib/secret.json')
```

But it halts without hesitation, giving me:

```
Error in httpuv::startServer(use$host, use$port, list(call = listen)) : 
  Failed to create server
Calls: gmail_auth ... init_oauth2.0 -> oauth_authorize -> oauth_listener -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

From the look of it, the error comes from `httpuv`. So I've resinstalled that:

```
devtools::install_github(c("shiny", "httpuv"), "rstudio")
```

But no love.

Adding to the mystery, my local Linux box can run the `gmail_auth` call without errors. This is a 'Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa'.

Maybe relevant:

> > [Shiny runExample Error - Fail to create server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613580/shiny-runexample-error-fail-to-create-server/19639607)

## LOCAL BOX:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NUMERIC=C                 
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8           LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8       
 [5] LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8       LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8      
 [7] LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8          LC_NAME=sv_SE.UTF-8          
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=sv_SE.UTF-8        LC_TELEPHONE=sv_SE.UTF-8     
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=sv_SE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gmailr_0.7.1        extrafont_0.17      ReporteRs_0.8.8    
[4] ReporteRsjars_0.0.2 DBI_0.7             rjson_0.2.15       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] zip_1.0.0         Rcpp_0.12.12      compiler_3.4.1    plyr_1.8.4       
 [5] bindr_0.1         R.methodsS3_1.7.1 R.utils_2.5.0     base64enc_0.1-3  
 [9] tools_3.4.1       digest_0.6.12     uuid_0.1-2        tibble_1.3.4     
[13] gtable_0.2.0      pkgconfig_2.0.1   png_0.1-7         rlang_0.1.2      
[17] shiny_1.0.5       bindrcpp_0.2      Rttf2pt1_1.3.4    rJava_0.9-8      
[21] httr_1.3.1        officer_0.1.5     dplyr_0.7.2       xml2_1.1.1       
[25] knitr_1.17        gdtools_0.1.5     grid_3.4.1        glue_1.1.1       
[29] R6_2.2.2          rvg_0.1.4         extrafontdb_1.0   ggplot2_2.2.1    
[33] purrr_0.2.3       magrittr_1.5      scales_0.5.0      htmltools_0.3.6  
[37] assertthat_0.2.0  xtable_1.8-2      mime_0.5          colorspace_1.3-2 
[41] httpuv_1.3.5      lazyeval_0.2.0    munsell_0.4.3     R.oo_1.21.0
```

## DEBIAN SERVER:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8          LC_NUMERIC=C                 
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8           LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8       
 [5] LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8       LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8      
 [7] LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8          LC_NAME=sv_SE.UTF-8          
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=sv_SE.UTF-8        LC_TELEPHONE=sv_SE.UTF-8     
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=sv_SE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gmailr_0.7.1        extrafont_0.17      ReporteRs_0.8.8    
[4] ReporteRsjars_0.0.2 DBI_0.7             RMariaDB_0.11-6    
[7] rjson_0.2.15       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] zip_1.0.0         Rcpp_0.12.12      plyr_1.8.4        bindr_0.1        
 [5] R.methodsS3_1.7.1 R.utils_2.5.0     base64enc_0.1-3   tools_3.3.3      
 [9] digest_0.6.12     uuid_0.1-2        tibble_1.3.4      gtable_0.2.0     
[13] pkgconfig_2.0.1   png_0.1-7         rlang_0.1.2       shiny_1.0.5.9000 
[17] bindrcpp_0.2      Rttf2pt1_1.3.4    rJava_0.9-8       httr_1.3.1       
[21] officer_0.1.5     dplyr_0.7.2       xml2_1.1.1        knitr_1.17       
[25] gdtools_0.1.5     grid_3.3.3        glue_1.1.1        R6_2.2.2         
[29] rvg_0.1.4         extrafontdb_1.0   ggplot2_2.2.1     purrr_0.2.3      
[33] magrittr_1.5      scales_0.5.0      htmltools_0.3.6   assertthat_0.2.0 
[37] xtable_1.8-2      mime_0.5          colorspace_1.3-2  httpuv_1.3.5     
[41] lazyeval_0.2.0    munsell_0.4.3     R.oo_1.21.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a days work finally solved it. I think...

R was blocking the `1410` port. And from what I found out, this port is needed by `httpuv`. However, after killing the R process a new error occured. The `httpuv` server seemed to start but the `gmailr` authentication needed to be re-run from a web browser, producing a fresh `.httr-auth`.

I'm guessing that R froze in the `waiting for authentication in browser...` state on my headless Debian server, effectively blocking port `1410`. After going through the authentication process on my laptop (the Mint machine), and moving the `.httr-auth` to the headless server, everything seems to work.

Exactly why this happened I don't know. But if everything works from now on, I'll accept the ignorance! Fingers crossed.